# Volume of a solid region enclosed by elliptic cylinder using triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Find the volume of a solid limited laterally by an elliptical cylinder $$\frac{(x-2)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{9}=1$$ and by the planes $z+x=5$ and $z+x=6$.

I tried doing by cylindrical coordinates and Cartesian, but I could not get to the answer, which is $6\pi$. Can anyone give me some ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Good attempt at writing LaTeX. Now just put dollar signs around your math

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use change of variable $x = 2 + 2r \cos \theta, y = 1 + 3r \sin\theta$

Your ellipse transforms to a circle of radius $1$ and so we have $0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$.

and the limits of $z$ will be given by planes

$3 - 2 r \cos \theta \leq z \leq 4 - 2r \cos \theta$.

Jacobian for the change of variables,

$|J| = 6r$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to get to the answer. My difficulties were to understand how to convert to other coordinates, and you really helped me to see were my mistake was. Again thank you for your help!